# data binding manually into Telerik Radgridview winforms

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

How to refresh telerik grid view (winforms) using c#?

i tried :

```
gridview.datasource = null;
gridview.datasource = dataset;
```

Comment: isn't there a DataBind() method on the telerik control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I saw your problem once earlier at the Telerik forum:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/radgridview-refresh-problem.aspx

you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface